# Flash content in browser dialog is not getting rendering with IE10 - Windows 8

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to launch window popup dialog. The dialog points to HTML page which loads swf file.
Everything works fine but in case of IE10 on Windows 8, the flash content is not getting rendering inside popup dialog.
I have verified that .swf file loads but it is not showing its content. If I close the dialog, the flash file conten get diaplay for a moment.

This isssue occurs if I open dialog using showModalDialog or showModalessDialog. Works fine if popup opened using window.open.

Reiterating again - this issue occurs only with IE10 on Windows 8. It works fine otherwise with IE10 on Windows 2012, Firefox on Windows 8 and on both browser in rest of the windows version.

Look at it get the clear idea - http://youtu.be/SupJYZoLk5I.

Requesting you to share your idea.

Thanks,
Prithveesingh.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: WEIRD. If you hide/show or resize the browser window (force IE or Flash to 'redraw'), does that also cause the swf to render properly?